# Implementation of an optimised 2-Dimensional subset sum problem in R

Tags: r, dynamic-programming, subset-sum

I am dealing with a variation of the well-known subset sum problem which I am really in need of some help with. In my problem, I have a matrix `m` with two columns(`a`, `b`) and `n` rows. I want to find the rows that the sum of the corresponding `a` and `b` values equal two target values (`a_target`, `b_target`). Some constraints are that `a_target`, `b_target`, `a`,`b` are all whole positive integers and I am only interested in the **first solution** that meets the criteria of the two targets being returned or, if no solution meets the criteria, the closest. This closest can be defined as the sum of the error across the two targets. As this method will be run on large datasets, I would need the solution to be optimised.

The problem could be set up as follows:

```
m <- matrix(data=sample(1:100, 200, replace=T),
            ncol=2,
            dimnames = list(
              NULL,c("a","b")
            ))
head(m)
      a  b
[1,] 44 80
[2,] 51 24
[3,] 31 68
[4,] 46 55
[5,] 34 98
[6,] 93 49

a_target <- 500 
b_target <- 700
```

To give some background, the ordinary [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) deals with finding any subset of a set of integers that sums to some target `t`, which is NP-complete. There are multiple methods to do this with varying time optimisations. One such package in R is `subsetsum`, [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/adagio/versions/0.7.1/topics/subsetsum). I have taken code form this package with an aim to modify it for use in my problem but I'm not sure if it is possible, for instance this solution requires `t` to be in increasing order to work so I'm not sure how applicable that would be with two `t` values. The code where t is a single column i.e. a vector is:

```
subsetsum <- function(S, t) {
  n <- length(S)
  inds <- NULL
  x <- logical(n)
  F <- numeric(t + 1)
  G <- logical(t + 1)
  G[1] <- TRUE
  print(paste("n,inds,x,F,G",n,inds,x,F,G))  
  for (k in 1:n) {
      H <- c(logical(S[k]), G[1:(t + 1 - S[k])])
      H <- (G < H)
      j <- which(H)
      F[j] <- k
      G[j] <- TRUE
      if (G[t + 1]) break
  }
  wch <- which(G)
  j <- wch[length(wch)]
  fmax <- j - 1
  while (j > 1) {
      k <- F[j]
      x[k] <- TRUE
      j <- j - S[k]
  }
  inds <- which(x)
  
  return(list(val = sum(S[inds]), inds = inds))
}
```

Comment: How big (i.e. how many rows) exactly is your real problem?

Comment: The size is variable with a max of somewhere around 25,000 rows